# Получить value с input jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

есть следующего вида механизм вывода списка из базы:

````php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  if ($row['active']==0){
    echo "<tr><form action= method=post>";
    echo "<td><input style='width:80%;margin-left:5%;' type=text name=id id=id class=sel  value='".$row['id']."'</td>";
     echo "</form>
        </tr>";
  }
}
Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на любой input передавалась его значение в скрипт. Не могу понять как это правильно реализовать, если использовать следующую конструкцию то передаёт значение первого Input'a (что логично):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.sel').click(function(){  
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "back/ajax_order.php",  
      data: "id="+$("#id").val(),  
      success: function(html){  
                 $("#body1").html(html);  
                }  
    });  
    return false;  
  });  
});
````

Как передать значение именного того input'a по которому произошло нажатие ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработчики событий jQuery вызываются в контексте DOM-элемента, событие которого обрабатывается.

```
...
data: "id="+$(this).val(),
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, ушёл учить матчасть.